# Add new array to text with serialize PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I'm trying to make a text file with some information (Date and IP List).

This is a PHP code for a new file:

```
//File
$History = history.txt";

//Date
$Today = date("d", time());

//New Data
$Data = Array("TIME" => $Today, "HISTORY" => Array(get_ip()));
//Write to text File

$objData = serialize($Data);
$fp = fopen($History, "w");
fwrite($fp, $objData);
fclose($fp);
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
[TIME] => 19
[HISTORY] => Array ( [0] => 127.0.0.1 )
)
```

After that, i need to add every new IP to the HISTORY. i wrote this part:

```
//Get Old Data
$FileRead = unserialize(file_get_contents($History));
if($FileRead[TIME] = $Today){
  //ADD NEW IP IN HISTORY PART
}
```

problem is, i don't know how i can add a new IP in my old file HISTORY array. i need to add new IP's and getting result like this:

```
Array ( 
[TIME] => 19
[HISTORY] => Array ( 
    [0] => 127.0.0.1 
    [1] => 127.12.0.2
    [2] => 127.192.0.1 
    [3] => 127.168.1.5
    [4] => ...
  )
)
```

how i can do that with serialize function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unserialize recreates the array that you serialized so all you have to do is add an occurance to it like so

```
//Get Old Data
$FileRead = unserialize(file_get_contents($History));
if($FileRead[TIME] = $Today){

   // check the array before adding
   print_r( $FileRead):

   $FileRead['HISTORY'][] = getip();

   // check the array after adding
   print_r( $FileRead):

   // and then serialize the data and save back into the file
}
```